# Mongoose does not save my data, error message: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, http, mongoose

What I am trying to do here is retrieve some data from an API and save it in my MongoDB database, here is my code:

```
const request = require("request");
const Vege = require("./models/Vege");

request(
    "https://data.taipei/api/v1/dataset/f4f80730-df59-44f9-bfb8-32c136b1ae68?scope=resourceAquire&limit=1",
    { json: true },
    (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        let data = body.result.results;        // an array of objects
        

        data.forEach(vege => {
            let trimmed = JSON.parse(
                JSON.stringify(vege).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g, '"')
            );           // just removing spaces

            const newVege = new Vege({
                品名: trimmed.品名,
                市場: trimmed.市場,
                "平均(元 / 公斤)": trimmed["平均(元 / 公斤)"],
                種類: trimmed.種類,
                日期: trimmed.日期,
            });
            console.log(newVege);              // I do see the object I want to save in the console
            newVege.save(err => console.log(err))      // "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
                .then(() => console.log("Saved successfully"));
        })
        
    }
);
```

When I do .save() to my newVege object and then check mongodb atlas collection it's not there, and the error message says "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined", which gets me confused because when I console.log the newVege it's exactly what I wanted. Not sure how it's undefined and why it's not saved. I appreciate any help!

----Update----

I kind of fixed the issue of data not saving by moving the above code to a "/" route, now the code looks like this

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    request(
        "https://data.taipei/api/v1/dataset/f4f80730-df59-44f9-bfb8-32c136b1ae68?scope=resourceAquire&limit=1",
        { json: true },
        (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            let data = body.result.results;

            for (const vege of data) {
                let trimmed = JSON.parse(
                    JSON.stringify(vege).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g, '"')
                );
                const newVege = new Vege({
                    品名: trimmed.品名,
                    市場: trimmed.市場,
                    "平均(元 / 公斤)": trimmed["平均(元 / 公斤)"],
                    種類: trimmed.種類,
                    日期: trimmed.日期,
                });
                
                newVege
                    .save()
                    .then((vege) => console.log(vege))
                    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json(err));
            };
        }
    );
});
```

But then I have a new issue which is when I test it with Postman, the request won't stop (keep saying sending requests and keep loading). If I click cancel and check my database, I do see the data saved. Any idea why it keeps sending requests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with Schema.save delay in mongoose tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124330/how-to-deal-with-schema-save-delay-in-mongoose-tests)

Comment: Promise error handling should be done with chained `.catch()` function rather than a callback function to .save()

Comment: or `try`/`catch` if using `async` functions.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link and advice, but I guess the real question is why my data is not saved?

Comment: @JeffreyLee to stop the request error. You have to end the request by doing something like `return res.send("done")`

Comment: `.then((vege) => {console.log(vege);  res.send("done")})`

Comment: @JeffreyLee you don't do anything with the `res` in the handler of the fulfilled promise. In the `.then`

Comment: @jackblank Thanks that works! Another thing I figured is that my ```request``` function has a same argument ```res``` and I was calling ```.status``` in the inner ```res```, and that doesn't return the outer function.

Comment: The naming collisions happen sometimes. If you have solved your problem with this question and thought I was helpful please choose my answer and or upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach is not to be used with asynchronous function like `save`
try using `for of`

Maybe like this

```
for(const vege of data){
  let trimmed = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(vege).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g, '"')
  );           // just removing spaces

  const newVege = new Vege({
    品名: trimmed.品名,
    市場: trimmed.市場,
    "平均(元 / 公斤)": trimmed["平均(元 / 公斤)"],
    種類: trimmed.種類,
    日期: trimmed.日期,
  });  
  newVege.save()
    .then(result =>{
     //result should contain the saved vege
     console.log("Saved successfully")
   })

}
```

Comment: The `for of` here is equivalent to the original `forEach`. Can you elaborate on why forEach shouldn't be used?

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. To simplify things `foreach` doesn't wait for the `.save` . `for of` does wait for async functions. That's my understanding.

Comment: `for of` doesn't wait, `await` waits. Both constructs can `await` a promise as long as it's used inside an `async` function.

Comment: `for of` lets you `await` the entire loop more easily.

Comment: You are probably right. But I know for sure that using`forEach` like the way the user has it definitely doesn't wait for the async function. I would never use a forEach that has an async function in the forEach handler. I would use `forOf` instead. I don't know the exact reasons why.

Comment: @Matt you know `for of` uses iterators, right? not arrays right? It handles the looping different.

Comment: Yes, but this is not an async iterator and nothing is being awaited for so there's functionally not much difference I can see. Never mind, it's sound advice anyway 
(op will probably find they want to wait for things pretty soon).